# strongSwan 5.1.2 on Ubuntu Trusty (14.0.4) and AppArmor

Tags: 14.04, apparmor, ipsec

I've configured VPN on Ubuntu Trusty with `strongSwan 5.1.2` and
connections are OK. Daemon is running as **root**.

But when i execute any **stroke** command via **ipsec** wrapper in Bash (**root** connection), it replies :
`reading from socket failed: Permission denied`

When i suppress `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.ipsec.stroke` AppArmor
profile, the command replies correctly.

This is the default AppArmor profile :

```
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/lib/ipsec/stroke {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  /etc/strongswan.conf          r,
  /etc/strongswan.d/            r,
  /etc/strongswan.d/**          r,
  /run/charon.ctl               rw,
}
```

I don't find what to add to make the command replies correctly.

Any idea ?

Thanks,
Fabrice Barconnière

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the exact same issue, but it only occurs some of the time.  Sometimes the ipsec command completes successfully, and sometimes the same command gets the permission denied error.  Removing the apparmor profiles fixes it:

```
apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.ipsec.charon
apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.ipsec.stroke
```

Definitely something in a recent patch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i have the same behaviour.
`ipsec` command is a wrapper of `stroke` command. Removing only `stroke` AppArmor profile is enough.